# C programming: Returning string from a function

Tags: c

I am tring to print compose a function can get the specific line from a file, like string=extract_line(2),  then the string will be the content of the 2nd line of a file.
but when I tried to put the function in a head file, I got Segmentation fault.

Here is my code:
test.c:

```
    #include "extract_line.h"
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
    {

        extract_line(2);
        extract_line(3);
        printf("%s\n", str);
        return 0;
    }
```

extract_line.h

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    #define TEMP_PATH "/home/pi/project/PCD_8544_screen/show_on_LCD/network_speed.txt"

    static char str[256];

    void extract_line( int Tgt_Line )
    {
        FILE *fp;
        fp=fopen(TEMP_PATH, "r");

        // char str[256];
        char holder;

        int line=0;
        while((holder=fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
            if(holder == '\n') line++;
            if(line == Tgt_Line) break; /* 1 because count start from 0,you know */
        }
        if(holder == EOF) {
            printf("%s doesn't have the 2nd line\n", fp);
            //error:there's no a 2nd
        }

        int i=0;
        while((holder=fgetc(fp)) != EOF && (holder != '\n' )) { 
            // putchar(holder);
            str[i] = holder;
            i++;
        }
        // printf("%s\n",str);
        fclose(fp);
        // return str;
    }
```

Comment: @seb I will add it later, but this isn't major problem.

Comment: Of course it is! How am I expected to guarantee that I've reproduced your behaviour without it? Perhaps your file is missing! Stop acting foolish.

Comment: Sorry, I am just new to C language.

Comment: Do you see how lengthy this answer got? If you followed *defensive programming*, that would've been one less issue to cover. Additionally, next time you get warnings from your compiler, **DO NOT IGNORE THEM!** If you don't understand them, ask questions about *the warning*, instead of asking questions about *the segfault*. Tell us which words confuse you, and we'll help you better understand what your compiler tells you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following line of code:

> ```
> printf("%s doesn't have the 2nd line\n", fp);
> ```

You're printing a `FILE *` as though it's expected to point at a string (filename?). As `printf` expects a `char *`, this is likely to cause irrational behaviour. Note that your compiler is probably SCREAMING at you about this! Perhaps you meant:

```
printf("%s doesn't have the 2nd line\n", TEMP_PATH);
```

---

Additionally, there's a possibility for a null pointer dereference which would also cause irrational behaviour between the following two lines:

```
fp=fopen(TEMP_PATH, "r");
// snip! you need to check fp here!
while((holder=fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
```

---

On that note, your loop is infinite on systems where `char` is an *unsigned* type, as `EOF` is negative which can't possibly compare equal to any unsigned values. As `fgetc` returns an `int` with an `unsigned char` within it and `holder` is a `char`, the downward conversion discards the information required for your loop to terminate. `holder` should be defined as an `int`, instead.

---

As there's no upper bound on how many characters are read set by your loop, it's possible that `str` may be accessed (and assigned) out of bounds in `str[i] = holder;`. This could cause irrational behaviour.

---

Additionally, it appears there's no explicit assignment of a `'\0'` string terminator. As `str` is defined with static storage duration (not to be confused with your `static` keyword, which provides internal linkage), that won't really cause irrational behaviour, in fact it's quite predictable, but your output might not be as you expect if the first call reads a line longer than the second call.

---

Finally, just a few nitpick notes:

- I suggest using `size_t` rather than `int` for variables which are expected to *count* or *refer to* array elements (e.g. `int i=0;` should be `size_t i=0;`). This is to make it explicit that negative numbers *aren't acceptable*, which might also speed your code up a little.
- It's a little bit strange to put code in header files. Usually definitions only go into header files, which we `#include`, and code goes into code files, which we link to (e.g. `gcc -o x.c` compiles x.c, then `gcc main.c x.o` compiles main.c and links it with x.o).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a main() function or you need to run the script from within any other function..

```
#include "extract_line.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main() {
  extract_line(2);
  extract_line(3);
  printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

Comment: What does [C11/5.1.2.2.1 *Program startup*](http://www.iso-9899.info/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1) say about *`void main()`*?